# Homemade Kernel linker global variables and inline Strings cannot be accessed

Tags: c, linux, linker, kernel, ld

I have followed some tutorials on the web and created my own kernel. It is booting on GRUB with QEMU succesfully. But I have the problem described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305075/simple-c-kernel-char-pointers-arent-working), and I cannot solve it. I can have that workaround described, but I also need to use global variables, it would make the job easier, but I do not understand what should I change in linker to properly use global variables and inline strings.

**main.c**

```
struct grub_signature {
    unsigned int magic;
    unsigned int flags;
    unsigned int checksum;
};

#define GRUB_MAGIC 0x1BADB002
#define GRUB_FLAGS 0x0
#define GRUB_CHECKSUM (-1 * (GRUB_MAGIC + GRUB_FLAGS))

struct grub_signature gs __attribute__ ((section (".grub_sig"))) =
    { GRUB_MAGIC, GRUB_FLAGS, GRUB_CHECKSUM };


void putc(unsigned int pos, char c){
    char* video = (char*)0xB8000;
    video[2 * pos ] = c;
    video[2 * pos + 1] = 0x3F;
}

void puts(char* str){
    int i = 0;
    while(*str){        
        putc(i++, *(str++));
    }
}

void main (void)
{
    char txt[] = "MyOS";
    puts("where is this text"); // does not work, puts(txt) works.
    while(1){};
}
```

**Makefile:**

```
CC = gcc
LD = ld

CFLAGS = -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m32 -g
LDFLAGS = -T linker.ld -nostdlib -n -melf_i386

SRC = main.c
OBJ = ${SRC:.c=.o}

all: kernel

.c.o:
    @echo CC $<
    @${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} $<

kernel: ${OBJ} linker.ld
    @echo CC -c -o $@
    @${LD} ${LDFLAGS} -o kernel ${OBJ}

clean:
    @echo cleaning
    @rm -f ${OBJ} kernel

.PHONY: all
```

**linker.ld**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386")
ENTRY(main)
SECTIONS
{
    .grub_sig 0xC0100000 : AT(0x100000)
    {
        *(.grub_sig)
    }
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)void main (void)
    }
    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.comment)
        *(.eh_frame)
    }
}
```

What works:

```
void main (void)
{
char txt[] = "MyOS";
puts(txt);
while(1) {}
}
```

**What does not work:**

**1)**

```
char txt[] = "MyOS";
void main (void)
{
    puts(txt);
    while(1) {}
}
```

**2)**

```
void main (void)
{
    puts("MyOS");
    while(1) {}
}
```

Output of assembly: (external link, because it is a little long) http://hastebin.com/gidebefuga.pl

Comment: Can you post the assembly the compiler generates? (`gcc main.c -S`, then post main.s). Also, I would try adding `-fpic` to CFLAGS, even though it shouldn't be needed if your kernel is getting loaded where you think.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I added the [main.s](http://hastebin.com/gidebefuga.pl). `-fpic` solved inline declaration, but  global declaration is still wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since I did any homebrew OS hacking, but I think you need to add an rodata section to your linker script.

Comment: thedaver64's suggestion might work. If not, which version is the assembly you posted for? We need to see the one that's not working.

Comment: It is the non-working one, I have tried to use xv6's linker script, but it still fails. [Xv6's linker script](http://hastebin.com/tolelugigu.avrasm)

Comment: Can you post the assembly for the inline version too? The string is being placed in the data section, so rodata won't be necessary, for now at least.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw [here is the inline version](http://hastebin.com/rixegacoxo.avrasm)

Comment: OK, I see a problem. The global version is not converting the array to a pointer, instead trying to read its contents as a pointer. Try defining the global as a `char*` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Strangely, it now outputs "S ", independent of the string I type, and [this is the related assembly result](http://hastebin.com/xutepihupi.avrasm)

Comment: It added a second dereference to do the same thing. I don't know what is going on, but it appears to be some sort of compiler error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37024/discussion-between-mustafa-and-ughoavgfhw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `objdump -h` output, you'll see that virtual and linear addresses do not match for any of the sections. If you look at `objdump -d` output, you'll see that the addresses are all in the 0xC0100000 range.

However, you do not provide any addressing information in the [multiboot header structure](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#OS-image-format); you only provide the minimum three fields. Instead, the boot loader will pick a good address (1M on x86, i.e. 0x00100000, for both virtual and linear addresses), and load the code there.

One might think that that kind of discrepancy should cause the kernel to not run at all, but it just happens that the code generated by the above `main.c` does not use the addresses for anything except read-only constants. In particular, GCC generates jumps and calls that use relative addresses (signed offsets relative to the address of the next instruction on x86), so the code still runs.

There are two solutions, first one trivial.

Most bootloaders on x86 load the image at the smallest allowed virtual and linear address, 1M (= 0x00100000 = 1048576). Therefore, if you tell your linker script to use both virtual and linear addresses starting at 0x00100000, i.e.

```
  .grub_sig 0x00100000 : AT(0x100000)
  {
      *(.grub_sig)
  }
```

your kernel will Just Work. I have verified this fixes the issue you are having, after removing the extra `void main(void)` from your linker script, of course. To be specific, I constructed an 33 MB virtual disk, containing one ext2 partition, installed grub2 on it (using 1.99-21ubuntu3.10) and the above kernel, and ran the image successfully under qemu-kvm 1.0 (1.0+noroms-0ubuntu14.11).

The second option is to set the bit 16 in the multiboot flags, and supply the five additional words necessary to tell the bootloader where the code expects to be resident. However, 0xC0100000 will not work -- at least grub2 will just freak out and reboot --, whereas something like 0x00200000 does work fine. This is because multiboot is really designed to use virtual == linear addresses, and there may be other stuff already present at the highest addresses (similar to why addresses below 1M is avoided).

Note that the boot loader does not provide you with a stack, so it's a bit of a surprise the code works at all.

I personally recommend you use a simple assembler file to construct the signature, and reserve some stack space. For example, `start.asm` simplified from [here](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~herbertb/misc/writingkernels.txt),

```
BITS 32
EXTERN main
GLOBAL start

SECTION .grub_sig
signature:
    MAGIC equ 0x1BADB002
    FLAGS equ 0
    dd MAGIC, FLAGS, -(MAGIC+FLAGS)

SECTION .text
start:
    mov esp, _sys_stack     ; End of stack area
    call main
    jmp $                   ; Infinite loop

SECTION .bss
    resb 16384              ; reserve 16384 bytes for stack
_sys_stack:                 ; end of stack
```

compile using

```
nasm -f elf start.asm -o start.o
```

and modify your linker script to use `start` instead of `main` as the entry point,

```
ENTRY(start)
```

Remove the multiboot stuff from your `main.c`, then compile and link to `kernel` using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -m32 -c main.c -o main.o
ld -T linker.ld -nostdlib -n -melf_i386 start.o main.o -o kernel
```

and you have a good start to work on your own kernel.

Questions? Comments?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! However, I am still having problems, it says error: unsupoorted flag: 0xe4524ffe under grub 2 and refuses to boot. I made a simple 50MB ext2 filesystem with GRUB2 too, and to make it easier, I uploaded it to [github:mustafaakin/myos](https://github.com/mustafaakin/myos). When I move the boot signature to main.c again, it works, and the global variable problem is solved. So, what is really happening?

Comment: @Mustafa: There was a missing comma in the assembly (between `FLAGS` and `-(MAGIC+FLAGS)`), causing only two (instead of three) words to be generated. The error you saw was the result of the boot loader not finding a valid multiboot header. Fixed now.

Comment: Oh, I see, thats how `dd` works, now runs perfectly, updating the repo with the changes now. I am allowed to offer bounty in 10 hours, so notify me If i forget it :) Thanks a lot, you made me clear many things.